# When I try to add a material Blender 2.8 crashes

Tags: materials

Running a Dell Precision M4600 with NVidia Quatro 1000M (2gb ram), 24 gb ram, and 1 Tb SSD primary drive and Windows 7 x64.

I have been using blender 2.79 flawlessly, but in 2.8 when I attempt to add a material to a mesh the app crashes.  As a test I moved my blender file to my acer spin ultrabook and the materials work great.

Comment: Make sure that your graphics driver is up-to-date.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the material the video RAM of the graphics cards is exhausted. When comparing the size of the video RAM of both computers...which one has more memory. Replace the material with a most simple one temporarily and repeat your tests. Do you experience any crashes then?